# Do I need a certificate on both servers if I'm making a secure connection to a remote mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, ssl

I need to make a secure connection using php to a remote mysql database.  Do I need to install ssl certificates on both servers? Or just in the server where I have the mysql database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you want to secure.

If you want to secure the communication between the user-agent (browser) to your web server, you need to set up a certificate on the web server.

If you want to secure the communication between the web server (the DB client) and the MySQL server, you need to set up a certificate on the MySQL server.

In addition, you could make the MySQL client (your PHP script) use a client-certificate to authenticate to the MySQL server. This might not be necessary if MySQL username/password are considered enough.

Answer (score 0):

The certificate resides only on the MYSQL server side if you want to connect from your script to the database.  Your database server does not ever initiate connections with your web code, so the web side would not need a certificate for DB communication.  If you want to secure the communication between the client browser all the way to the DB, then you need a certificate for the website for the client browser to consume.